# Total sum of rows that has same column value

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I want to get the total value of multiable  columns hat has same value.

Ex. I want to sum all Angry reacts in month 1, 2, 3 .... etc. but I want the total of each month alone

```
MONTH    | ANGRY | DISGUST | HAPPY |......|PEOPLE
0        | 99    | 87      | 92    |      | 250
1        | 200   | 45      | 12    |      | 400
.
.
.
11       |....................................|
```

[Database Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDfs7.png)

Comment: Seriously consider revising your schema. A database table is NOT a spreadsheet.

Comment: Looks like a job for [GROUP BY](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sql-group-by/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be looking for simple aggregation:

```
select 
    month, 
    sum(angry) angry,
    sum(disgust) disgust,
    sum(happy) happy,
    ...
    sum(people) people
from mytable
group by month
```

---

Also, as commented by Strawberry, you should probably consider fixing your schema. Instead of having a bunch of columns, you could have just three:

```
date   -- a legitimate datetime column
mood   -- angry, disgust, ...
value  -- an integer value
```

With this set-up in place, your would be abe to generate a report with a query like:

```
select year(date), month(date), mood, sum(value) 
from mytable 
group by year(date), month(date), mood
```

Answer (score 0):

**use `groupBy`**

```
  $data = DB::table('your_table_name')->select(
            DB::raw('sum(angry) as sums'))
  ->groupBy('months')
  ->get();
```